Cannot paste from GBoard Clipboard button in an input element of type number
I use an input element of type number to submit a code received by SMS.
I made a little jsFiddle to test on your phone
<input type="text">
<div style="margin-top: 16px;">
  <button id="copy">Add value in clipboard</button>
</div>


I know I can make it work using input element of type text but isn't there any other solution to use input element of type number?

I visited your jsfiddle using safari on iOS .. and after clicking the button, that number was correctly pushed to the clipboard since when pasting the clipboard content inside that input shown on your page, the correct value gets shown 54321. Ok but you clearly talked about GBoard Clipboard actually so it's another scenario
